# I have a database. How do I create a trigger that uses information from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, create-table

I have created these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE oferta
(
    id_agentie INT,
    id_spatiu INT,
    vanzare CHAR(1),
    pret INT,
    moneda CHAR(5),
    CONSTRAINT pk_oferta PRIMARY KEY(id_agentie, id_spatiu)
);

CREATE TABLE Spatiu
(
    id_spatiu INT PRIMARY KEY,
    adresa VARCHAR(45),
    zona INT,
    suprafata INT,
    id_tip INT
);
```

I need to create a trigger that, whenever I insert a new 'pret'.If the value of 'pret' is less than 2 * 'suprafata', then I'd like to change the value of 'pret' into 2 * 'suprafata' and the value of 'moneda' into 'EUR'.

I have tried, but I couldn't manage to get it done.

EDIT: I am using MySql. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that should anwser your need.

The trigger will run before each insert on `oferta`. It will first run a query to recover the value of `suprafata` in the corresponding record of table `spatiu`, then compare it to the `pret` value passed to the insert order. When `pret` is (strictly) less than twice `suprafata`, the trigger modifies the values of `pret` and `moneda`.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON oferta
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE v1 INT;
    SELECT suprafata INTO v1 WHERE id_spatiu = NEW.id_spatiu;
    IF ( NEW.pret < 2 * v1) THEN
        NEW.pret = 2 * v1;
        NEW.moneda = 'EUR';
    END IF
END//
DELIMITER ;
```